# Virtualbox content in a external drive

Tags: virtualbox, debian, operating-systems

I bought a very old Toshiba laptop for hobby and I wanted to install Debian woody on it. Doing it physically is quiet cumbersome since you have to make a special bootable floppy disk so it would accept to boot up from CD drive, and then burn a compact disk (that's not the hard part).

I want to know if I can load the Debian Linux (woody) operating system I configured in VirtualBox onto the laptop's hard drive (I can connect it), or not.

**Tl;Dr : Can I load the operating system content I made in Virtual box into an external hard drive and boot from it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if the hardware is close enough (e.g. the VM should be configured with an IDE disk). A virtual machine in VirtualBox works more or less like a real machine, it has its own complete HDD image stored in the `*.vdi` file – you could use something like `qemu-img` to convert it to "raw image" format, then write the resulting image directly to the laptop's disk (e.g. over a USB IDE adapter).

Comment: thank you so much user1686, this gave me a lot of hope!!